# selenium docker-compose: Add implicit wait timeout

Tags: selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=30

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    volumes:
      - "/dev/shm:/dev/shm"
```

I have a test case failure whose stacktrace is as follows:

```
Capabilities {

    acceptInsecureCerts: true, 
    browserName: firefox, 
    browserVersion: 62.0, 
    javascriptEnabled: true, 
    moz:accessibilityChecks: false, 
    moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.22.0, 
    moz:headless: false, 
    moz:processID: 6052, 
    moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.M1QvZi..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, 
    moz:webdriverClick: true, 
    pageLoadStrategy: normal, 
    platform: LINUX, 
    platformName: LINUX, 
    platformVersion: 4.4.0-1066-aws, 
    rotatable: false, 
    timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000

}
```

My test case is failing as the webdriver is trying to locate an element in the application even when the web page has not loaded properly.

In Before method I have added two timeouts, implicit wait and page load timeout and both are set to 45 seconds. My question here is, when I am getting an RemoteWebdriverException and the capabilities show that implict is set 0, are the two implicit waits same or different?

If they are the same then why is it showing 0? And if they are different, what does it mean and is there any way to explicitly change the value from 0 to lets say 45?

P.S: I am getting this exception thrice in five times I execute it and it is only occurring for Firefox. I am executing my test cases in parallel, where parallel="methods" and thread-count="3",  which previously was 5 as I was getting memory shortage issues, which are now not coming.

Comment: What happens when you run the tests sequentially(without parallel and thread-count parameters)? Also, update the question with code snippet you are using to set capabilities and initiate the driver?

Comment: For sequential execution, its working as designed. But my concerns are regarding timeouts and not the results. But still, let me share a snippet of the code:                                                          
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(getConfig().getTargetUrl());
loginPage.login(getConfig().getAutomationUsername(),getConfig().getAutomationPassword());

Comment: I dont see the capabilities and driver instance creation code. You shared the configuration after you initiate the driver